# SQL query to find list names which contain specified key value pair where list contain values of type json

Tags: mysql, json, rawsql

user 1 - [{"domain_id":1},{"domain_id":2}]

user 2 - [{"domain_id":2}]

how to get all those users whose domain_id = 2,here domain_id is a json key

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Its not clear if these JSON String are what is stored on your database or if they are how you receive the parameters to be placed in the query? Can you elaborate please

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809822/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013037/