# How to filter values from JSON array in MariaDB?

Tags: filter, mariadb, mysql-json

I have a table which saves the score reached by some students in different schools. It has 2 columns, `school_name` and `students` (type json).
The table is similar to this:

| school_name | students |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Pear School | `[ { "name": "John", "passed": 1 }, { "name": "Mary", "passed": 1 } ]` |
| Big Blue School | `[ { "name": "Bob", "passed": 1 } ]` |
| Oak Tree Academy | `[ { "name": "Caty", "passed": 1 }, { "name": "Mark", "passed": 0 } ]` |

I want to select all rows from my table, but the `students` column should be filtered by the `passed` key, and only match those student that have a `"passed": 1`, so the expected result from my query should be:

| school_name | students |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Pear School | `[ { "name": "John", "passed": 1 }, { "name": "Mary", "passed": 1 } ]` |
| Big Blue School | `[ { "name": "Bob", "passed": 1 } ]` |
| Oak Tree Academy | `[ { "name": "Caty", "passed": 1 } ]` |

This is the query I tried so far:

```sql
SELECT 
    school_name, 
    /* Extract from the JSON array the student objects that matched the condition  */
    JSON_EXTRACT(
        students,
        /* Get only the index '$[*]' */
        TRIM(
            TRAILING '.passed'
            FROM JSON_UNQUOTE(
                /* Search the path for all students that passed exam */
                JSON_SEARCH(students, 'all', '1', null, '$[*].passed')
            )
        )
    )
FROM mytable
```

This query works ok when there is only one student in the json array, but if there is more than one student that match the condition, then the `JSON_SEARCH()` function would return an array containing the matches, and the rest of code would fail.

This is the report of my attempt:

| school_name | students |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Pear School | NULL |
| Big Blue School | `{ "name": "Bob", "passed": 1 }` |
| Oak Tree Academy | `{ "name": "Caty", "passed": 1 }` |

The NULL value appears because of the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function.

---

If I ommit the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function, and use this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    school_name, 
    /* Get only the index '$[*]' */
    TRIM(
        TRAILING '.passed'
        FROM JSON_UNQUOTE(
            /* Search the path for all students that passed exam */
            JSON_SEARCH(students, 'all', '1', null, '$[*].passed')
        )
    )
FROM mytable
```

The report would be this:

| school_name | students |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Pear School | `["$[0].passed", "$[1].passed"]` |
| Big Blue School | $[0] |
| Oak Tree Academy | $[0] |

How can I achieve this with pure mysql, thanks in advance!

---

#### Version

```sql
SELECT VERSION()

+-----------------+
|    version()    |
+-----------------+
| 10.4.18-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` report?

Comment: Parse-filter-pack back.

Comment: @BillKarwin Updated with the report

Comment: I don't see where you have stated the version of MySQL you are using, which is what I asked for. The solution to do this with JSON is to use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) but that requires you have MySQL 8.0. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58013321/20860

Comment: @BillKarwin Sorry, here it is `version()
10.4.18-MariaDB`

Comment: Okay, you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and both have been adding features ever since then, sometimes in incompatible ways. I don't use MariaDB, so I have no answer to offer.