# MySQL, JSON_CONTAINS usage on array

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

How to use 'JSON_CONTAINS' by such structure in MySQL `JSON` field?
`[{"uuid": "a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8"}]`
Doing this way:

```
SELECT * from tables c where 
    JSON_CONTAINS(c.data, '64a3104c-01e6-417b-8a11-bf5af73ad87d', '$[*].uuid')
```

but getting error

```
Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: 
"The document root must not be followed by other values." at position 2.
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your instance? That is, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @BillKarwin 8.0.27-18

Comment: @BillKarwin this question not answered there... can't adopt any of those approaches and don't need other than 'JSON_CONTAINS'

Comment: @Luuk no, it's not searching by array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [JSON_CONTAINS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) says:

> An error occurs if target or candidate is not a valid JSON document, or if the path argument is not a valid path expression or contains a * or ** wildcard.

This means you can't use JSON_CONTAINS() unless you're searching for a value at a *specific* path.

Also the second argument must be a JSON document, not a string.

```
mysql> SELECT * from tables c where
       JSON_CONTAINS(c.data, '"a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8"', '$[0].uuid');
+----+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | data                                               |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"uuid": "a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8"}] |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This works, but only because I made the value a JSON string (enclosed in double-quotes), and I searched for a fixed position in the array.

I assume you want to search for that value at any position in the array, not only `'$[0]'`.

The solution in MySQL is to use JSON_TABLE() so you can map the array into rows, and then use a WHERE condition.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tables c CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(c.data, '$[*]' COLUMNS (uuid CHAR(36) PATH '$.uuid')) AS j WHERE j.uuid = 'a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8';
+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | data                                               | uuid                                 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"uuid": "a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8"}] | a07b50ca-42f0-4d2b-b0a2-f2980deb03d8 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

If you find the way JSON implements JSON doesn't fit your needs, then I recommend storing data in normal rows and columns. You commented on [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58013321/20860) that this leads to additional joins, but *that's a normal part of SQL.* It's like saying you don't want to use for-loops in Java.

Comment: Thanks, the tricky part is using both: double-quotes and "[0]". I thought from that other topic that [0] would search only by first array element...
Regarding joins - yes, they are acceptable for solutions that overlook code complexity and performance implications. However, in the real world, these factors need to be considered sometime. In other parts of project I do use joins )
Anyway I appreciate you for the magic spell )

Comment: `'$[0]'` does search only the first element in the array. If you want to search for a value in a specific key in any element of the array, use the JSON_TABLE() solution I showed.

Comment: hm. Finally I understood, I didn't want to believe and read what I expect to find ) The only way is to extract as a column )
Thanks again )

Comment: To be an effective software developer, you have to resist confirmation bias. Understand how things work, not how you want them to work.

Comment: I gave up being effective. Social connections wins, not effectiveness. Now I don't like json in mysql ) Anyway there is no indexes in json, it's like work with plain text )